# Laravel5.1 can you passed an incremental variable in to a sub-view

Tags: laravel-5.1, laravel-blade

I am trying to pass an incremental variable to a blade template subview to add a number to a class name.

```
@for($x=1; $x < 4; $x++)
    <div class="col-md-3">
        {!! Form::label('amenIcon'.$x,'Amenity Icon '.$x) !!}
        {!! Form::select('amenIcon'.$x,
         [null =>'Choose Icon'] + $iconDirectory)
            !!}
    </div>
    @include('portal._iconModals')
@endfor
```

The sub-view portal._iconModals

```
<div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Choose Icons</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12" id="bsnImage">
                    @foreach($brandSocialIcons as $bIcons)
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="iconChoice{{$x}}"><img src="../../../../storage/icons/{{$bIcons}}"></a>
                    @endforeach
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to increment the class name iconChoice because the I have 3 select fields with options that use the same subview but because of the class name when I choose one of the images with the class of iconChoice it chooses it for all 3 select list instead.

Here is the js code

```
$( "#amenIcon1" ).click(function() {

     $('.iconChoice').click(function() {
         var $thumb = $(this);
         console.log($thumb);

         var icon1 = $thumb.find('img').attr('src');
         displayIcon1(icon1)
     });
     function displayIcon1(icon1) {
         $("#icon1Thumb").attr("src",icon1);
     }
 });
```

Might not be the best explanation but I will to elaborate more if need be. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass a variable with `@include` you can do:

```
@include('portal._iconModals', ['x' => $x])
```

Hope this helps!